# Component inner react state update on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I created a `Button` component that handle promise with automated loading process:

```js
import React, { FunctionComponent, useState } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, TouchableOpacityProps, StyleProp, TextStyle, ActivityIndicator, Alert,
} from 'react-native';

// Stylesheets and variant not related stuff.

export const Button: FunctionComponent<ButtonProps> = ({
  onPress, title, titleStyle, variant, disabled, confirmation,
}) => {
  const variantStyle = variants[variant || 'secondary'];
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const handlePress: TouchableOpacityProps['onPress'] = (event) => {
    const process = (): Promise<void> => Promise.resolve(onPress ? onPress(event) : undefined)
      .then(() => setLoading(false))
      .catch(() => setLoading(false));

    setLoading(true);
    if (!confirmation) {
      process();
    } else {
      Alert.alert(confirmation.title, confirmation.message, [
        {
          text: confirmation.cancelLabel || 'Annuler',
          onPress: () => setLoading(false),
        },
        {
          text: confirmation.confirmLabel || 'Confirmer',
          onPress: process,
        },
      ]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={[
        styles.button,
        variantStyle.button,
        disabled ? styles.buttonDisabled : {},
      ]}
      onPress={handlePress}
      disabled={disabled || loading}
    >
      {
        loading
          ? (
            <ActivityIndicator
              color={variantStyle.buttonTitle.color}
            />
          )
          : (
            <Text
              style={[
                styles.buttonTitle,
                variantStyle.buttonTitle,
                disabled ? styles.buttonTitleDisabled : {},
                titleStyle,
              ]}
            >
              {title}
            </Text>
          )
      }
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export default null;
```

The main goal is quite simple: Avoids to created thousand of `const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);` across my apps screens and simplify the code base for easier understanding and maintenance.

It works very well on 99% of cases even with react-navigation screen changes, unless for this case:

```js
<Button
  title="OK"
  onPress={() => navigation.reset({
    index: 0,
    routes: [
      { name: 'Home' },
    ],
  })}
/>
```

This causes the famous `Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.` error.

I managed to simplify and isolate the case like this:

```js
const Parent: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [shown, setShown] = useState<boolean>(true);

  const toggleShow: ButtonProps['onPress'] = () => {
    setShown(!shown);
  }

  return (
    <>
      {shown
        ? <Button title="I will go out." onPress={toggleShow} />
        : <Text>See? I'm gone.</Text>
      }
    </>
  )
}

return <Parent />;
```

And indeed, because the component is destroyed when the promisified function is resolved, the `setLoading` call throw the error.

After many searchs and tries, I read from [this blog post](https://medium.com/@shanplourde/avoid-react-state-update-warnings-on-unmounted-components-bcecf054e953):

> Unless you’re not using a state management solution like Redux, your only real option is to move state management up in your hierarchy.

Well, that is a quite frustrating situation, because the main goal was to reduce the number of loading state declaration, not growing them.

Here is a proper way, or at least an alternative, to keep this refactoring working with this case memory leak problem managed properly?

I also read article about `isMounted` and `useEffect` usage, but I don't really see how to apply them to my component.

Note: The error appears on Expo only the first time following the app start.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a minimal example of how to know if your component is mounted or not:

```
function FunComponent() {
  _isMounted = false;
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    _isMounted = true;
    return () => {
      _isMounted = false;
    }
  });

  async function doNetworkingStuffThatTakesTime() {
    return "much fast";
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    doNetworkingStuffThatTakesTime().then((response) => {
      _isMounted && setSomeState(response);
    })
  });

  return null;
}
```

I suspect the piece you didn't know about `useEffect` is that whatever function you return is run as the `beforeComponentUnmount` lifecycle event.

Comment: Thanks. The issue with your example is the missing `onPress` event function. Where should place my logic on your example?

Comment: I did a try but with no luck: https://gist.github.com/soullivaneuh/dadbf459a86c8baf4bc6473638ea91d6